# (Troll Math Question) Divided by sweets

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

I got "x" number of sweets. I can divide my sweets equally by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 all the way to 101 friends such that I have no left overs. Find the least number of sweets I could possibly have at first?

Note: This logic is a troll, so I thought it is fun. Wanna see how people answer. Anyways, the answer is still a number. Not kidding and it is possible. No cutting of sweets happened.

Comment: Can I answer $-\infty$?

Comment: @GlenO Aks yourself if u can have a -infinity sweets

Comment: It's a troll question, I figure a troll answer is appropriate.

Comment: @GlenO Its logical though.Actually.Imagine yourself in real life.How much sweets do u actually need to give out to equalise the nunber of sweets each friend have?

Comment: I know. But sometimes it's fun to intentionally reinterpret things. In mathematics, there's really nothing stopping $x$ being a negative number, unless you specify otherwise. The context does introduce a "natural" lower limit, but technically you can't divide zero sweets among 101 friends because there's nothing to divide - we overlook that nuance of words used in regular English because it's a mathematical question... but we could equally ignore other nuances. Mostly, though, I asked because it seemed like a fun idea to suggest it. I was hoping you'd laugh at it.

Comment: @GlenO ahh I see.Thanks.Welp, I will have to think of another question then.

Comment: Troll question?  Here's a troll comment: The specified set of "numbers" does not include 0 or negatives.  The (not specified) set of "whole numbers" does include 0.

Comment: @GlenO: I would tend to disagree with you there.  You can [divide a set of zero objects into two groups with none left over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evenness_of_zero).  And if you can do two groups, why not any number of groups?

Comment: I don't think you'll have friends after this is over :)

Comment: @Kevin - I was referring to common English usage of "divide" instead of the mathematical term. I know full well that zero is divisible by all non-zero integers.

Comment: @GlenO: Just look at the empty balance scale illustrating that article.  I'd say they managed to divide zero in half under the common English definition.

Comment: @Kevin - I didn't say English definition, I said English usage. You'd never hear a person describe the act of dividing zero objects between 2 people, because there's nothing to divide. It makes mathematical sense, and you can certainly explain it to people, but if you asked someone to divide a pile of clothes into two equal piles, and pointed to an empty space, they wouldn't say "done", they'd say "there's no pile of clothes there".

Comment: For completeness' sake the LCM of 1..101 is 7041757898200960193617914702466542659236800

Comment: @Kevin because there is no such computation of where $n > 0$ and that fits n/0.Thats why I avoided setting the question as "zero friends".

Comment: @GlenO: If you're going to restrict us to "What normal people would say," you're eliminating nearly all of the puzzles on this site, *especially* the [logic-puzzle] tag.

Comment: @Kevin - As I said, the intent is to provide justification for a troll answer to what is explicitly called a troll question. At no point did I say that the interpretation that was intended by ministic was a bad one. Just that I could take the reasoning further and justify a $-\infty$ answer, for the troll purpose.

Comment: Im surprised it already reached 1000 views

Comment: The minimum number of sweets *obviously* is $x_{\rm min}$.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Troll question?

> The minimum number of sweets you can have is clearly 0.

Comment: What about -0? A troll answer for a troll question? :p

Comment: Yeah, you got it.I wanted someone to give me a mathematical solution of finding the lowest common multiple of these and be like giving a large answer.

Comment: @ministic2001 - then you shouldn't have listed it as a troll math question. Kind of a big red flag for "don't use the obvious answer you first think of".

Comment: @MarkN that works.But it is still 0.-0 and 0 no differs in its value

Comment: @ministic2001 But hang on, zero can also be divided by 102, so it can't be the answer... Unless that's your 'logical' weasel wording (i.e. you never said it _can't_ also be split among 102, 103, 104... friends.) Right?

Comment: @grkvlt Tyen would u expect me to day that I can split to an infinity friend? The answer would be obvious right? All it needs is to to satisfy the question.If yiur answer does not satisfy the division of 102 and above, it didnt say it needs to.

Comment: @grkvlt, there is no number divisible by 2, 3 and 17 that is not also divisible by 102, so that isn't a valid counter point (sorry). This is because 2, 3, and 17 are the prime factors of 102, and are all coprime. Yay math!

Answer (score 26):

For the non-zero answer, in ruby, type:

> (1..101).reduce(:lcm)

Which yields:

> 7041757898200960193617914702466542659236800

Don't eat them all at once, I guess.

Answer (score 19):

Just for fun, the answer is also:

> $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(\frac{-(\sqrt{-0} \times sinh(f'(x)))^3}{π^e})dx$

Comment: BWAHAHA.Even though Im just 14 years old, I get this :P.

Comment: Now i feel stupid, what's the joke?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Don't feel bad, I added more to it (Just look for the simple thing, maybe then you will see it).

Comment: SPOILER TO THE JOKE: The numerator has the sqrt(0) in it.

Comment: @MarkN Bah! Words.

Comment: Assuming $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: you forgot the dx

Comment: Isn't $0\times\infty$ an indefinite value, not $0$?

Comment: Wouldn't this make the answer any constant value..?

Comment: @No.7892142 Only if it was indefinite. You can look it up in wolfram if you want :)

Comment: @Ypnypn: [Improper Riemann integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) are defined as limits, so you have $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(x\cdot0)$ which is zero. For Lebesgue integration, you usually define $0\cdot(+\infty)=0$.

Answer (score 15):

X = 1

You have one sweet for yourself, and your 1-101 friends are all *imaginary friends* for whom you conjure an appropriate amount of *imaginary sweets*.

Comment: Lol :) Nice little joke here.Sometimes math like my exam paper just doesnt make sense that we had to make jokes like these :)

Comment: Maybe they could also just be 1-101 reflections of yourself in a mirror, so they are imaginary, but also real ;)

Answer (score 14):

Your sweets are powdered candy. You simply divide the amount you have into portions of equal weight, no cutting required. Probably something to the effect of a kilogram of candy for a satisfying portion when divided by 101.

Answer (score 12):

The real answer is

> $-\infty$

In fact, you didn't specify that the solution is in $\mathbb{N}$, it could also be in  $\mathbb{Z}$ ! The least number satisfying your problem is $-\infty$.
What does it mean that I have $-\infty$ sweets? It simply means that instead of having them, you have a debt of $-\infty$ sweets (exactly as $-20\$$ means a debt of $20$ dollars).

Comment: It means you have an infinite number of sweets, but they all want to eat you :)

Comment: In the most common number systems there is no such number as $-\infty$. Please also specify the number system.

Comment: Since when was $-\infty$ in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: wouldn't "least" imply an ordering which is not present on Z?

Comment: @Meelo With −∞ I mean an integer number which is always lower than any other integer, doesn't matter what number you choose.

Comment: @Chris There's no order in Z? So you mean that (-1)>(-2) is false?

Comment: *I mean an integer number which is always lower than any other integer.* There is no such integer. $-\infty$ is not an integer just as $+\infty$ is not a natural number.

Comment: @leoll2 Z is not *well* ordered, which is probably what Chris meant.  This answer is entirely false, because $-\infty\not\in\mathbb Z$.  Further, there is no least integer.

Comment: I may just be getting confused on what Z is... :) Its a while since I had to think about these things. :) I was thinking of complex numbers sinze they often use the variable z. I'll just go get my coat. :)

Comment: `The real answer is` $- \infty$. Since when $- \infty$ is "real". :P

Comment: I counter with surreal numbers, and the equivalent to $-\infty$ for them, $-\mathrm{No}$. That's the gap below all surreal numbers, which is much smaller than $-\infty$ which is just the gap between negative finite and negative infinite numbers. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**EDITED**

In case you wanted a non-troll (less troll?) answer, the smallest number divisible by 1-101 that's also greater than zero would be:

> 7041757898200960193617914702466542659236800

Solution:

> I see how my previous answer was incorrect, I just missed a few steps.  Not only do we need the product of every prime from 1 to 101, but we need the largest power of each prime that is itself less than 101.  This is because every number less than 101 can be factored as a combination of prime numbers, but also, any factor of a number n is necessarily less than n.
>
> So not only do we need...
>
> 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37*41*43*47*53*59*61*67*71*73*79*83*89*97*101
>
> We'll also need to include:
>
> The largest power of 2 that is less than 101 (64 = 2^6)
>
> The largest power of 3 that is less than 101 (81 = 3^4)
>
> The largest power of 5 that is less than 101 (25 = 5^2)
>
> And the largest power of 7 that is less than 101 (49 = 7^2).
>
> The smallest power of 11, the next prime number, is 121, which is too large.  Thus, our final product becomes:
>
> 2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3*3*5*5*7*7*11*13*17*19*23*29*31*37*41*43*47*53*59*61*67*71*73*79*83*89*97*101
>
> = 7041757898200960193617914702466542659236800

Indeed, another answer using Ruby seems to have given the same result.  This, above, is the mathematical proof of that.

Comment: 232862364358497360900063316880507363070 is obviously not divisible by 100, or any other non-[squarefree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html) number.

Comment: To expand on what @kgull said with a short counterexample: imagine you want a number divisible by 1-6. The product of all the primes between 1-6 would be 2*3*5 = 30. But 4∤15.

Comment: Ah, indeed.  My mistake.  I shouldn't try large computations after three glasses of whiskey.

Comment: There we go.  Think I did it right this time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm being too simplistic. If(as the question states)

> I got "x" number of sweets

then I must have

> something and thus not 0

My intuitive guess is

> + or - (n!) sweets (dont forget the units as my old maths teacher used to say) where n is the number of friends you have.

also the answer given by Mark N cannot be a full answer as

> the solution to an integral adds a constant - there is no mention in this solution of how big (or little) the constant is.

Comment: Imagine this question:Solve "x" for the following equation 2x+6=6 where "x" becomes 0. Also, because to prevent obviousity, I have to put "number of sweets" rather than "no sweets"."I have 0 number of sweets", to me, make sense.Maybe it will be clearer if I said "I have "x" sweets.

Comment: but like grkvit pointed out, 0 is also devisable by 102, 103, 104 ... so the aswer cannot be 0

Comment: lol - I love the English language! I think to the last question the answer is 11 because if you were short of sweets then not everyone got one. If you had 29 sweets there would be 11 sweets left over (after everyone else got one sweet each).

Comment: The solution to an [indefinite integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteIntegral.html) adds a constant. [Mark N's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/12956/10035) as of [22 hours ago](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/12956/revisions) includes the limits negative infinity to infinity, making it a [definite integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DefiniteIntegral.html) and thus an exact value.

Comment: @Brian, any number that satisfies the original question that isn't zero is also divisible by any number composed of two primes less than or equal to 101, so 101 and 2 which is 202. The answer didn't specify that it couldn't be divisible by anything else, and it would be impossible for it not to be.

Comment: @ministic2001 Why would you give two sweets each to 18 friends if you didn't have it? You didn't specify you were giving two to each of them, so that makes the assumption make no sense. The 7 sweets short is fine if you say 2 each, but 11 makes more sense with the first two statements before your question, since you wouldn't try to divide more than you had. When you have less than one for everyone, you'd be more likely to say you are short candy.

Comment: ... Just because you're not solving math equations, doesn't mean you aren't doing math. Math is more than algebra, and in fact, everything in this question is math directly applied to a real world question. Generally, someone else has done the math for you, such as speed limits which are often decided based on statistics, a form of applied math. However, I was arguing against your choice of wording here, which was improper to convey your meaning. And that's not math. That's English.

Comment: However, word problems like that will never appear in the real world. You are right to say you won't solve algebra problems to find out a speed limit. That's Monty Python levels of silly, even.